# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, site-name, domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name unix.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

At some point if this turns into the success we all want it to be, we need to select a domain name.

So let the suggestions begin.

Please indicate if the *domain* is **available**, **used**, or just **parked**. Also please don't post more than *one* domain per answer so we can vote on them individually.

Comment: **if**? How dare you doubt the eventual success of....whatever we call this

Comment: I've only found two things certain in this life: death and taxes.

Comment: I suspect tax is the only universal constant. After all, we might invent immortality but *someone* will charge you for it...

Comment: Ooh ooh I know we could call it slashdot you know... /. hahah. (mod's self -2)

Comment: how 'bout superuser? since windows doesn't have one... oh damn

Comment: @xenoterracide: might as well use dotslash...

Comment: I have one for Ubuntu SE *unu.com* it's an acronym for *Ubuntu's Not Unix*. haha

Comment: @xeno Your bitterness is showing again :)

Answer (score 44):

**kernelpanic.com** If they're willing to pay it...

The domain is for sale... so... *parked*

Comment: kerneloops.com is free, however, it might clash with kerneloops.org? Not posted separately as along very similar lines to your suggestion.

Comment: I think their parked page suggests they want $9,930 for it?

Comment: @fluteflute yeah something like that... which isn't super cheap but then again... If I recall SE is well funded so it shouldn't be impossible either.

Comment: I really like the the KERNELPANIC.COM domain name... and I want to propose that the community setup an escrow account to raise the money to buy that domain. With roughly 1000 members in this community, the cost is about $9 each... less if more people join the community... Just my 2c.

Comment: @Jonas ... I don't donate money to for profit businesses ...

Comment: Like the name a lot! Would fit nicely with "StackOverflow" and "ServerFault"

Comment: Incredibly brilliant name. $10k seems achievable.

Comment: @TJCrowder And rather fitting, given the pseudo-mod rep limit on the non-beta sites :)

Answer (score 12):

rm-rf.com (AVAILABLE for purchase)

Comment: This is my favorite.

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion:

manunix.com (man unix). There is actually a manual page for "man unix" which isn't about the system itself so that might cause confusion. However, sticking my neck out... eeek.

Domain is currently unregistered.

Answer (score 7):

**beardedguru.com**? :-P

*edit:* domain is available

Comment: beardandsuspenders.com

Answer (score 4):

**unix.stackexchange.com**

Comment: Our SE subdomain will continue to point to us (at least for a while) when/if we get a new domain, but assuming we do ever get our own domain we should have a choice ready

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I posted it to see how it ranks against the other available suggestions. It is certainly better than the names I personally suggested (now deleted).

Answer (score 1):

**varquestions.com** I'm thinking like if we stored questions in unix it'd be `/var/questions`.

*available*

Answer (score 1):

**coredump.com**

*seems parked*

Answer (score 0):

fsckit.com - It appears parked, [not really used](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Afsckit.com). One (broken) link.

Answer (score 0):

**kernelstall.com**

is *available*

Answer (score -1):

**allaboutunix.com** which is free

Answer (score -1):

**hashbang.com** AVAILABLE, **Shebang.com** used, or **shbang.com** appears parked but in chinese I don't really know.

Comment: I weirdly like `hashbang.com`, but it's [not available](http://www.whois.net/whois/hashbang.com). Interestingly, it resolves to 127.0.0.1, so you can use it as a localhost substitute; I'm not sure why they did that

Comment: That is really weird.  It's not occupied. Can't find anything about it on google. but some guy in San Fransisco owns it. May be he would be willing to sell for less than the $10,000 for the kernelpanic.com

Answer (score -2):

- forkbomb.co (AVAILABLE)
- forkbomb.com (TAKEN)

Answer (score -2):

rmrfroot.com (AVAILABLE) (`rm -rf /` if someone didn't get it)

Answer (score -2):

**dashdashhelp.com**

*available* (and so is [minusminushelp.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/why-do-unix-heads-say-minus))

**dashh.com** is taken, but the owners don't seem to do much with it so it might be grabbable. Ditto for minush.com.

Answer (score -2):

**v6andup.com** *not registered*

Answer (score -3):

**shellhackers.com** feels too much like SO overlap, and possibly other upcoming area51 sites.

*available*

Answer (score -3):

**procversion.com** Thought of this from `cat /proc/version`

*available*

Answer (score -3):

eliza.com

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA

(currently parked)

Answer (score -4):

**manerrno.com** of course this is unix for manual error number.

*available*

Answer (score -5):

Here is my try:

- younicks.com
- rtfman.com