# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: personal opinion "blah" I like kernelpanic.com

Comment: @xenoterracide poking because I am interested in this but can't find more info: Did this actually happen? I mean taking a domain name? If not, why didn't it?

Answer (score 6):

KernelPanic (kernelpanic.com): We'll seal your broken pipes, tighten your sockets, repair your devices, and even wipe your windows.

Comment: I actually like the *we will wipe your windows* humor, even though it's controversial - it's the sort of thing why others call us fanbois.

Answer (score 6):

Tagline: sudo make me understand

The construction is an allusion to [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/149/). I think the surface meaning (“make me understand” with some unix-related thingy) is still comprehensible if you don't get the allusion (can people who haven't seen that cartoon confirm or infirm?).

Comment: I like the `sudo` notion, although "make me understand" is a little long-winded. There must be a way to express the same thing in one word, but I'm failing at coming up with it now

Comment: @Michael: “sudo make me” has to stay for the xkcd allusion (and it works better with “make” being a standard unix command). Anyway four words is perfectly reasonable for a tagline.

Comment: "sudo answer my inquiry"

Comment: "sudo enlighten me" A bit too religious, perhaps. ;)

Answer (score 3):

KernelPanic: We'll fix your broken pipes, tighten your sockets, and give you a shiny, reliable operating system.

[similar alternative if you like this one](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/239#239)

Comment: +1 for a good Elevator Pitch

Answer (score 3):

afterthemanpage.com is available, and it suggests what people should do before posting a question.

"Read the man page and you're still stuck? afterthemanpage.com"

Answer (score 2):

date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep

Sex is better than unix... but we're here for your upright moments.

Comment: just, kinda... it's funny but I feel not professional

Answer (score 1):

KernelPanic: Panicking since 1969

Answer (score 1):

KernelPanic: We're in our 40s and have lots of kids, man are we proud!

Answer (score 1):

Have burning questions about the intimate details of Linux and Unix? This is the place to ask them.

Want to spread some Linux and Unix love to others and learn more yourself? Start here.

Comment: I vote for the first one.

Comment: *burning*? you should get that checked out.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is bad form, but I'll borrow the tagline I proposed over at [askubuntu.com](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/405/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/407#407), partially because they've gone off down [another thread](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/372/our-community-in-one-brief-sentence).

> Learn by asking. Learn by example.

Comment: You've inadvertently hit upon another tagline: "Unix SE: we take the stuff the Ubuntu SE doesn't want" ;)

Comment: "Unix: We were here before Ubuntu."

Comment: kinda like how we were before...well a lotta stuff actually.

Answer (score -1):

KernelPanic: Jump out of a window! Inquire or inform about Unix and Linux.

or

"Jump out of Windows!" (if you prefer)

Answer (score -3):

unix.stackexchange.com The least social-behaviourly challenged experts on Unix you'll find in the net. No matter if your home is the terminal or the GUI, here you'll find the answers you are looking for.

Comment: P.S. English isn't my native language and I'm not sure if "social behaviourly challenged" is even something you may say in English. Feel free to improve.

Comment: In the old days, "social behaviorally challenged" was commonly used to describe Debian ;).

Comment: I think "socially challenged" is more brits ( english ) , but then again I'm not brits either ;)

Answer (score -3):

unix.stackexchange.com : It's like Unix, but friendly.

Answer (score -3):

Ask about Linux, because **Linux is sexy**

---

or instead of 'ask about', just

Use Linux, because it's sexy

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure if we should only use Linux as tagline?

Comment: mmm lol... don't be critical, change it if you like :)

Comment: Is Unix not sexy? What about FreeBSD? Isn't it more nerdy? I've been told that MacOSX is sexy.

Comment: well...  `linux is sexy` is meme, and I sacrificed "FreeBSD" to make the tagline catchy.... but they are all sexy... i promise

Comment: What's with the Linux favoritism? and besides, there's a so much better quote about unix and sexy...

Comment: @Gilles, If you have something better, please share..