# How about a rename?

Tags: discussion, site-name

I think the site should be renamed to **Unix family**, instead of the rather dull and arrogant **Unix & Linux**. It's like saying **Linux and Ubuntu** instead of **Linux family** (if the site was just for Linux systems).

Comment: It's too bad one can't google for "*nix" or "un*x" - I'd be curious to compare those to "unix family" and "unix-like". For what it's worth, "unix-like OS(es)" is far more common than "unix family", but unix family is probably a cleaner name for a title.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/why-is-there-a-when-there-is-mention-of-unix-throughout-the-internet

Comment: @Jefromi: We've just had the [Is Linux a Unix?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091) question on the main site.

Comment: I don't really find it arrogant, and I don't think your analogy is particularly persuasive: Linux, though unix-like, is not A Unix, while Ubuntu is absolutely a Linux [distribution]. This is not to say that the current name is perfect; I'm just not totally sure about your reasons.

Comment: @ Jef Bad analogy, I agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The advantage of “Unix and Linux” is that a lot of the potential audience has heard of Linux but not of Unix. And it's short and flows well, unlike the more correct “Unix including Linux” or “Unix, Unix-like, Unix-derived, Unix-emulating, Unix-simulating, Unix-inspired, Unix-resembling, Unix-flavored, Unix-shaped, Unix-tasting, and/or otherwise and without limitation Unix-y systems, including, but not limited to, Linux, GNU/Linux, Lignux, GNU/X11/Linux, [GNU/X11/Apache/Linux/TeX/Perl/Python/FreeCiv](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-linux-faq.html#many), and other systems that may contain Linuts”.

Granted, this argument could be stretched to mean the site should be called “Unix and Linux and Mac OS X's non-GUI bits”, but that would be a bit long.

“Unix and Linux” might be taken to imply that non-Unix-like Linux platforms (e.g. Android) are on-topic. This hasn't been decided yet, although the lack of questions can be interpreted as saying they're off-topic.

Comment: +1: I think the current title does convey the desired meaning fairly well, especially given its length. I expect anyone out there using a unix-like OS which *isn't* unix or linux probably knows enough to realize they're within the scope. (Though if it turns out later we absolutely must append FreeCiv, so be it!)

Comment: @Jefromi: I should have mentioned that this GNU/Linux/... bit is not mine, it's from the GNU project.

Comment: I wouldn't say lack of questions is interpreted as offtopic, but more ask lack of interest... I'm pretty sure there was a is "embedded linux ok" question here on meta at some point.

Comment: Tastes Like Unix. Yummy. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with you. This is nitpicking and is not actually a good brand (*personal opinion*).

I think we should be renamed to "Kernel Panic". I'd say that's just me... but [these](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/184/29) [threads](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be) disagree.

In any sense... you should probably post your suggestions on the [elevator pitch thread](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/184/29) which is exactly about our branding... If you'd like to pitch it, that's the correct place, as opposed to starting a new thread.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Kernal Panic" is already taken, sadly enough...

Comment: @samb nope, still for sale